# Timestamp with auto increment in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timestamp

Want to write System.currentMiliseconds in the cassandta table for each column by cassandra. For example

```
writeToCassandra(name, email)

in cassandra table:
--------------------------------
name | email| currentMiliseconds
```

Can cassandra prepare currentMiliseconds column automatically like auto increment ?

BR!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with: `dateof(now())`

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (NAME, EMAIL, DATE)
                VALUES ('NAME',  'EMAIL', dateof(now()));
```

Comment: No, I should delegate to cassandra does this operation.

Comment: I do not understand, exactly what you want

Comment: I should exactly know when cassadra driver write column. Becouse I can send this dateof(now()) and my network will have delay. In my case I should exactly know when "timestamp" cassandra driver write the column. You see ?

Comment: but dateof(now()) it's executed on the db server... you want the timestamp  from the service, before the sql statement is executed in db?

Comment: no, I want to get timeStamp when cassandra driver will store row into table. 
Does it dateof(now()) provide this ?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what it does, you can try though :) and see for yourself

Comment: i gave him a possible answer based on his not that detailed question

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra has some sort of columnar database taste inside. So if you read docs how the columns are stored inside SSTable, you'll notice that each column has a personal write timestamp appended (used for conflict resolution, like last-write-wins strategy). You can query for that timestamp using writetime() function:

```
cqlsh:so> create table ticks ( id text primary key, value int);
cqlsh:so> insert into ticks (id, value) values ('foo', 1);
cqlsh:so> insert into ticks (id, value) values ('bar', 2);
cqlsh:so> insert into ticks (id, value) values ('baz', 3);
cqlsh:so> select id, value from ticks;

 id  | value
-----+-------
 bar |     2
 foo |     1
 baz |     3

(3 rows)
cqlsh:so> select id, writetime(value) from ticks;

 id  | writetime(value)
-----+------------------
 bar | 1448282940862913
 foo | 1448282937031542
 baz | 1448282945591607

(3 rows)
```

As you requested, I've not explicitly inserted write timestamp to DB, but able to query it. Note you cannot use writetime() function for PK.